# Что означают треугольные скобки в Java (дженерики)

Tags: java

Я видел что используются для `ArrayList<String>` но понятия не имею что это. Может кто объяснит без ссылок на умудренный справочник оракл.

Comment: это способ не писать тип женерика если он явно виден из типа объекта к которому его присваивают. Пример `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>()` но `Object list = ArrayList<Integer>()`

Comment: ты меня не совсем понял, я переформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Не надо минусовать! Когда был новичком сам таким вопросом задавался и не мог ответа найти!

Comment: @Duoxx боюсь коротко ответить не получится и придётся читать. Кратко - это типизация женерика. Примерно как шаблоны в С++ и прочее. Для коллекций - это тип хранимого значения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Надо минусовать. Особенно за комментарий выше. Привел бы строчку кода - не было бы минусов.

Comment: Ладно, удалю вопрос.

Comment: @Duoxx, не надо. Лучше посмотрите мой ответ - может что-то понятнее станет)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вы не читали учебник?! Удивлён.

Comment: Треугольные скобочки..

Comment: я не писал скобки в уменьшительно ласкательном

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, читал когда-то, но то ли там не было про дженерики, то ли я до них не дошёл, то ли они были непонятно показаны... В итоге я их понял только когда на работе надо было допиливать код где они активно использовались. Вот тогда пришлось понять, а потом и полюбить)

Comment: щас бы учебники читать)))

Comment: Я тогда был еще очень глуп не стоит судить по прошлому

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дженерики используются для возможности писать классы, в которых часть переменных (или возвращаемых значений методов) не имеет заранее определённого типа и позволяет использовать разные типы для внутренних переменных. Например в случае `List` позволяет создавать списки из чисел, строк или любых других классов. Переданный в треугольные скобки `<>` тип становится типом массива, который используется внутри реализации `List` и методы типа `get` и `set`реализации `List` начинают отдавать этот определённый программистом тип.

Таким образом дженерики позволяют писать обобщённые реализации классов с заранее не известными типами внутренних переменных. Это очень удобно и круто, хоть по началу и не понятно)

Пример:

```
public class MyClass<T> {

    T foo;

    public T getFoo() { return foo; }

    public void setFoo(T foo) { this.foo = foo; }
}
```

Т.к. в этом классе заранее не определён тип переменной `foo`, то она может быть любого типа.

```
//тип определён нами как Integer, значит только его (и его потомков) можно использовать при пользовании этого экземпляра
MyClass<Integer> integerFoo = new MyClass<>();
integerFoo.setFoo(5);
//integerFoo.setFoo("5"); - ошибка компиляции, т.к. String не Integer


//тип определён нами как String, значит только его (и его потомков) можно использовать при пользовании этого экземпляра
MyClass<String> stringFoo = new MyClass<>();
stringFoo.setFoo("5");
//stringFoo.setFoo(5); - ошибка компиляции, т.к. Integer не String
```

---

Если бы дженериков не было бы, то, например, использование списков было бы болью - при получении объекта из него его пришлось бы каждый раз в ручную кастовать к нужному типу (или, что хуже - создавать по одной реализации списка на каждый тип данных для списка):

```
//без дженериков
List listOfObjects = new ArrayList();
listOfObjects.add("string");
//требуется кастануть руками объект к строке
String stringFromObjectsList = (String) listOfObjects.get(0);

//с ними
List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listOfStrings.add("string");
//НЕ требуется кастовать руками объект к строке
String stringFromStringList = listOfStrings.get(0);
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно пример?

Comment: Прям выручил, просто читал книгу про java везде они использовались а в самой книге не объяснялись

Comment: @Duoxx, пример добавил в ответ)

Comment: https://ideone.com/cL7Hg6

Comment: Да вещь полезная.

Comment: А в дженерики можно передать исключение?

Comment: @Duoxx, смотря что вы имеете в виду. Так-то исключения суть классы, засим можно. Например для создания класса, который может кидать разные типы исключений